# Why does this eval not work in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can you explain this?

I want to eval values and calculations from two different sources. One source gives me the following info(programmatically):

```
'a = 2'
```

The second source gives me this expression to evaluate:

```
'a + 3'
```

This works:

```
a = 2
eval 'a + 3'
```

This also works:

```
eval 'a = 2; a + 3'
```

But what I really need is this, and it doesn't work:

```
eval 'a = 2'
eval 'a + 3'
```

I would like to understand the difference, and how can I make the last option work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could create a [`Binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html), and associate the same binding with each [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) call:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > b = binding
 => #<Binding:0x00000100a60c60> 
1.9.3p194 :009 > eval 'a = 2', b
 => 2 
1.9.3p194 :010 > eval 'a + 3', b
 => 5
```

This way any variables that you create in earlier `eval` calls are available later on (as long as you use the same binding object).

Instead of using `Kernel::eval`, you could use [`Binding#eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html#method-i-eval), which would make the association clearer:

```
1.9.3p194 :011 > b = binding
 => #<Binding:0x00000100b46aa8> 
1.9.3p194 :012 > b.eval 'a = 2'
 => 2 
1.9.3p194 :013 > b.eval 'a + 3'
 => 5
```